# Bound ItemsControl not updating before displaying

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I have a `UserControl` that is comprised of a few bound `ItemsControl`'s and `strings`, and based on the button that is pressed, different data is displayed.  Here is an example of one of the `Button`'s click events:

```
private void LeftPreviousScoresButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (m_previousScoresWindow.Visibility == Visibility.Visible)
    {
        m_previousScoresWindow.Hide();
    }
    else
    {
        WindowTitle = "Left Side";
        PreviousScoresA = m_previousLeftWristErosionScoresReaderA;
        PreviousScoresB = m_previousLeftWristErosionScoresReaderB;

        m_previousScoresWindow.Show();
    }
}
```

There are several of these click event listeners which assigns `WindowTitle`, `PreviousScoresA`, and `PreviousScoresB` with the associated data. The `UserControl` then binds to them like this:

```
<ItemsControl Height="Auto" Width="Auto"
              ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=ParentForm, Path=PreviousScoresA}" 
              Grid.Row="1" />

<ItemsControl Height="Auto" Width="Auto"
              ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=ParentForm, Path=PreviousScoresB}" 
              Grid.Row="2" />

<TextBlock FontSize="16" FontWeight="Bold" Height="25" 
           Margin="5" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Foreground="Black" 
           Text="{Binding ElementName=ParentForm, Path=PreviousScoresWindowTitle}" />
```

However, when opening the window, the old data displays for a second before it is updated with the current data.  I've even tried adding these calls when calling `Hide()` on the `Window` but it didn't seem to help:

```
WindowTitle = String.Empty;
PreviousScoresA = new ObservableCollection<PreviousScoreData>();
PreviousScoresB = new ObservableCollection<PreviousScoreData>();
```

Is there any way to ensure that `Show()` is not called until after the bound data has been updated? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As it appears you are using an `ObservableCollection`, the collection should never be re-initialized. Rather, it should just be cleared and then add the new values; this is what helps keep the collection synchronized when using an `ObservableCollection`.

This is a bit of a shot in the dark based on your code sample; if you clear the collection when hiding and then refill them with the new values, then you should get the desired effect:

```
private void LeftPreviousScoresButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  if (m_previousScoresWindow.Visibility == Visibility.Visible)
  {
    m_previousScoresWindow.Hide();
    WindowTitle = string.Empty;
    PreviousScoresA.Clear();
    PreviousScoresB.Clear();
  }
  else
  {
    WindowTitle = "Left Side";

    // do not re-initialize the collection; clear and add new values
    // PreviousScoresA = m_previousLeftWristErosionScoresReaderA;
    // PreviousScoresB = m_previousLeftWristErosionScoresReaderB;
    ReFillScores(PreviousScoresA, m_previousLeftWristErosionScoresReaderA);
    ReFillScores(PreviousScoresB, m_previousLeftWristErosionScoresReaderB);

    m_previousScoresWindow.Show();
  }
}

private void ReFillScores (ObservableCollection<PreviousScoreData> collection, IEnumerable<PreviousScoreData> values)
{
  collection.Clear();
  foreach(PreviousScoreData d in values)
  {
    collection.Add(d);
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried that but the issue persists.  Why should an `ObservableCollections<>` never be re-initialized?  Should a `List<>` be used instead?